# Creating an expandable Recycler View

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I have gone through other questions as well, but couldn't figure out something. I want to create a User list using the Expandable `RecyclerView`. The way I want it to be

[image]

My `RecyclerView` part is all done. Now my question is how can I achieve this expandable `RecyclerView` part programmatically. And if I can do this using any library which one would be best to use.

Comment: This doesn't seems a Expendable one its just a View show/Hide .

Comment: @ADM So, how can I do this inside the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library to achieve expandable recyclerview.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view